# Lyx LayoutFile.cpp (171): LayoutFileList::Read: no textclasses found! in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: latex, lyx

As other questions have suggested, I just installed all texlive packages into my system and it did not solve the problem of Lyx not finding classes.

Has this been fixed since 12.04 or is it still a problem?

Could this be related to the texlive directory being outside the original texmf system?

[Same Old problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256125/lyx-doesnt-work-cant-find-cls-files)

Comment: And what is your problem?

Comment: Your screenshot is too small to be readable.

Comment: lyx can't find tex classes to work properly.

Comment: removed tree image

Answer (score 1):

I solved this using this post.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197730/lyx-not-accessing-styles-classes-and-bibliographies

> Please try backing up your LyX home folder (find its location in Help > About) and then removing it. Do that without LyX running. Then start LyX.

You need to delete your home .lyx directory from outside of lyx and then rerun lyx.  It reconfigures and then the class .cls files are found. Must be a caching issue.